# Thymeleaf: Iterating over elements of property of object of form

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf form which I would like to make dynamic, without using JS. The form should fill an object of class `ProjectNewDto`

```
public class ProjectNewDto {

    private List<UsernameAndPps> usernamesAndPps;

    ...
}
```

Therefore holding a list of `UsernameAndPps` elements:

```
public class UsernameAndPps {
    private String username;
    private double pps;

    ...
}
```

The controller puts the object as an attribute of the model and intialize the list of `usernamesAndPps` with a single element:

```
@RequestMapping("/projectNewPageR")
public String projectNewPage(Model model) {
    if(!model.containsAttribute("project")) {
        ProjectNewDto project = new ProjectNewDto();
        project.setUsernamesAndPps(new ArrayList<UsernameAndPps>());
        project.getUsernamesAndPps().add(new UsernameAndPps("user",100.0));

        model.addAttribute("project",project);
    }
    return "views/projectNewPage";
}
```

And then I try to show it with thymeleaf as

```
<form id="new_project_form" action="#" th:action="@{/views/projectNewSubmit}" th:object="${project}" method="post">
    <div th:each="usernameAndPps : $(project.usernamesAndPps)">
        <input type="text" th:value="${usernameAndPps.username}"></input>
        <input type="number" th:value="${usernameAndPps.pps}"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Create</button>
</form>
```

I have also tried with `$(usernamesAndPps)` instead of `$(project.usernamesAndPps)`, but the error remains the same:

```
Could not parse as each: "usernameAndPps : $(project.usernamesAndPps)"
```

I have removed a lot of other sytle related suff, but the is still an error of some kind. Any ideas?

The next step will be to add another button to add elements to the `usernamesAndPps` property. Lets keep positive here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I answer it, but I should delete it.

Braces instead of parentheses

```
<div th:each="usernameAndPps : ${project.usernamesAndPps}">
```